# how to access a folder of a mysql server and copy its files into different names files?

Tags: python, mysql, pyodbc

how to access a folder of a mysql server for instance the stored procedures folder, and copy its files into different names files locally? 
I can use pyodbc to connect to the database but how to connect and copy a folder on the database?

Comment: Is this simply another way of asking your previous question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/43270760/2144390)?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it appears to be a rehash of essentially [the same question you have already asked, about an hour prior to this one](http://stackoverflow.com/q/43270760).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to backup stored procedures or schema from a mysql DB using PYODBC](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43270760/how-to-backup-stored-procedures-or-schema-from-a-mysql-db-using-pyodbc)